# My SliderMenu is coming under the tab and selecting home is not going on specific tab

Tags: android, menu, tabs, drawerlayout

My SliderMenu is coming on tab how to fix that. This is my activity_main.xml with screen shot. Along With this I want to go on **Encode** tab when I select **Home** from menu but it's not happening until I go to some other option then select back home. This is my logic to navigate through tabs and `activity_main.xml`.

[image: screenshot]

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
              android:id="@+id/toolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
              app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
              app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

          <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
              style="@style/AppTabIndicatorLayout"
              android:id="@+id/tabs"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
              app:tabMode="fixed"
              app:tabGravity="fill"  />
      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

      <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/viewpager"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

      <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          tools:openDrawer="start">

          <include
              layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

          <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
              android:id="@+id/nav_view"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="start"
              android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
              app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
              app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

      </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the DrawerLayout as the parent of the layout and the NavigationView to be a direct child of the DrawerLayout and should be the last item.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                style="@style/AppTabIndicatorLayout"
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"  />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Now menu icon from the top left is gone not able to open menu.

Comment: You can open it by swiping and you can set the toolbar Home as up indicator to your burger menu item and add an action to it